# error in running the executable file of opencv

Tags: opencv, user-interface, gtk

I am trying to run the executable file with the code
=>`"LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/local/lib/" ./read_img"`

## But I receiving the error message like.

```
Gtk-Message: 01:38:08.815: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: 01:38:08.815: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(read_img:3318): Gtk-WARNING **: 01:38:08.901: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(read_img:3318): Gtk-WARNING **: 01:38:08.902: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(read_img:3318): Gtk-WARNING **: 01:38:08.904: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
```

i had checked that the `gtk` and `gail` are already been installed in the system default location

But still I am getting this error.